# rearranging a text file corpus in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have a text file, df.txt with following lines:

This is sentence 1

This is sentence 2

This is sentence 3

This is sentence 4

This is sentence 5

This is sentence 6

I would like to get another text file as

This is sentence 1 This is sentence 2

This is sentence 3 This is sentence 4

This is sentence 5 This is sentence 6

I tried:

```
import itertools
block = ''
with open('df.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, value in enumerate(itertools.islice(file, 2)):
        block += value
print(block)
```

which is not close:

This is sentence 1

This is sentence 2

I assume a similar post should be here but I could not find. Thank you for help.

Comment: Thank you for feedback @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

**Demo:**

```
lines = []
with open(filename) as infile:                          #Open file for read
    for num, line in enumerate(infile):                 #Iterate Each line
        if num % 2 == 0:                                #Pair lines
            lines.append(line.strip())
        else:
            lines[-1] = lines[-1] + "    " + line


#Write File
with open(filename1, "w") as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

**Output:**

```
This is sentence 1    This is sentence 2
This is sentence 3    This is sentence 4
This is sentence 5    This is sentence 6
```

---

Using `itertools.islice`

```
from itertools import islice

lines = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    while True:
        next_2_lines = list(islice(infile, 2))
        if not next_2_lines:
            break
        lines.append("\t".join(next_2_lines).replace("\n", "") )

#Write File
with open(filename1, "w") as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line+"\n")
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. The first part (Demo) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
block = ''
with open('df.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines),2):
        block += lines[0]+" "+lines[1]+"\n"

with open("output.txt", "r") as output_file:
    output_file.write(block)
```

Comment: Thank you Taohidul.